# What and why are these "flames" coming out behind a railgun projectile?

Tags: velocity, projectile

A cursory glance of [the Wikipedia article on railguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) reveals that railguns are electromagnetically powered. Its attached focus image depicts a 3.2 kg projectile being fired out of one at 2520 m/s.

[image]

Why are there "flames" coming out of the projectile? Is it because it is due to ablation from aerodynamic heating or is it something else? It shouldn't come from the gun itself because it is electricity-powered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to me it seems like ablation of the projectile.  The orange-white color is characteristic blackbody radiation from the tiny solid particles shed by the projectile and heated to 1000s of degrees by the shockwave/aero heating.  It is the same effect that causes a campfire or any sooty flame to look orange/yellow. So while it's not a flame per se, the same effect causes the light and color in both cases.

The greenish color may be an emission line corresponding to the projectile's material. (Note: Iron has fairly strong lines in green and blue?)

You'll see the same result with spacecraft reentering the atmosphere.

Comment: I expect that there is some ionization of the rails that are used to launch the projectile, as the current through those rails is absolutely HUGE.

Comment: Would that add to the visual effect in some way?

Comment: RC_23, in my opinion, yes, the plasma that gets produced would add to the visual effects.